# How to scale a histogram so it sums to a specific value?

Tags: c++, opencv, histogram

I have computed a histogram with `cv::calcHist`, and I want the histogram to sum to 100.  In the old OpenCV API, you could use `cvNormalizeHist(histogram, 100);`.  How do you do this in the new C++ API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you want [`cv::normalize()`](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/operations_on_arrays.html), specifically the overload taking a `MatND` since that's what `cv::calcHist()` outputs.

Comment: Would the call be something like cv::normalize(&hist, &hist, 0, 100);?

Comment: Try it.  While the documentation does not explicitly say you are allowed to use the same object as the source and destination, the documentation for `copyTo` does allow it, so there's at least a decent chance it will be fine.

Comment: That did not result in the expected output. hmm.. doesn't seem to be working that way. Although yes, you can have the same src and dst.  The other parameters aren't clear though

Comment: I'd try passing `normType=NORM_MINMAX`.

Answer (score 0):

how about [cv::normalize](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/core_operations_on_arrays.html#cv-normalize)?